# Xamarin databinding into current properties

Tags: xamarin, data-binding, properties

I am trying to get some strings into current.properties but am not sure how to do so the right way.

Right now i am creating a Label with the binding and then afterwards getting the label.text into the property but it seems to a bit stupid:

```
var userLabel = new Label {};
userLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "name");

Application.Current.Properties["studentName"] = userLabel.Text;
```

Looking forward to an easier way ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround:

```
class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    string text;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        Text = "York";
    }

    public string Text
    {
        set
        {
            if (text != value)
            {
                text = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Text");
                Application.Current.Properties["Text"] = text;
            }
        }
        get
        {
            return text;
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Set `BindingContext`:

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    MyViewModel mainPageViewModel = new MyViewModel();
    BindingContext = mainPageViewModel;
}
```

Use it in your `label`:

```
<Label Text="{Binding Text}">
```

For more detailed information, you could refer to: [Xamarin Forms Data Binding Basics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-binding-basics).